# Does ''desu'' and ''desu ka'' go with ''kara''?

Tags: grammar, words

From what time ?

Should I say ''Nanji kara ?'' or ''Nanji kara desu ka ?''

From August.

Should I say ''Hachi gatsu kara desu.'' or ''Hatchi gatsu kara.''

My book gives it without the ''desu'' but I just feel it might be a bit abrupt.

I'm a beginner btw

Comment: You're asking about the usage of *kara*, right? Did you mean "Hachi gatsu **kara** desu" and "Hatchi gatsu **kara**"?

Comment: Yeah , thanks for spotting my typo. I've put the karas in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good question.

1. 何時から? Nanji kara?
2. 何時からですか? Nanji kara desuka?

Both are the valid and correct, however, #1 is mostly in oral and #2 is always used in formal and oral. In other words, #2 is more polite than #1.

1. 8月から
2. 8月からです

The same explanation of above.